# Will it make any diffrence to my script if i use && instead of AND?

Tags: php

Can any one tell, will it make any difference if I use **&&** operator for condition instead of **and** in my php script?

For e.g

```
if($i == 1 and $bool == true)
```

is same as

```
if($i == 1 && $bool == true)
```

It will be better if anyone tell me difference between them.

Comment: is there even an "and" conditional operator. I did some quick searching but didn't find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `&&` and `and` is [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): `&&` has a higher one.

If you evaluate boolean expressions, I would stick with the most common used: `&&` and `||`.

**Update:**

Example:

```
a || b and c
```

evaluates as

```
(a || b) and c
```

whereas

```
a || b && c
```

evaluates as

```
a || (b && c)
```

Comment: Why would anybody think adding 'and' to the language was a good idea && what excuse is there for making it operate differently?  A synonym I could forgive, but this...

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is operator precendence, i.e if you mix and match types which ones are evaluted first.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

php being the frankenlanguage that it is, I would personally fall back on my General Orders:

1. If you are maintaining an existing code base, determine the coding standard inherent within it(if there is one)
2. If you are maintaining an existing code base with no apparent coding standard, establish one and as you work through the code base make the code adhere to the new coding standard (do not, however, modify code that is working bug free)
3. If you are writing new code, establish a coding standard, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

There is precedence issue only about using whether && or And, Moreover i recommend you to use && in numerical type comparisons and phrase comparisons "And", "Or". These make more sense to me. they'll increase the readability in your code.